# Prove that the function $\cos(x)$ is continuous using the topological definition

Tags: general-topology, continuity

We know that $f: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}})$ is continuous $\iff$ $\forall a< b \in \mathbb{R}, f^{-1}(]a,b[)\in \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}} $
I'm trying to apply this to the function : $f: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}}) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}}), x \mapsto \cos(x)$.
Let $a\lt b\in\mathbb{R}$.
if $f^{-1}(]a,b[)=\phi$ then $f^{-1}(]a,b[)\in\mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}}$ an open subset. 
if $f^{-1}(]a,b[)\not=\phi$ then $x\in f^{-1}(]a,b[)$$\iff$$\cos(x)\in]a,b[ \in \mathcal{T_{\mathbb{R}}}$$\implies$$\exists c\lt d\in \mathbb{R}$ : $\cos(x)\in ]c,d[\subseteq ]a,b[$.
Any help Please.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, you may want to use the following property of $\cos$ (which is easily proved):

> For any $x, y \in \Bbb R$, we have $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)| < |x - y|$.

This is known as ($1$-)Lipschitz.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this property..  I have tried to use it but I couldn't place it anywhere in the proof.

Comment: Try to show that, for any $x\in f^{-1}(]a, b[)$, there exists $r > 0$ such that the interval $]x - r, x + r[$ is contained in $f^{-1}(]a, b[)$.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally figured it out .
We continue the previous proof by letting $\varepsilon = min\{\cos(x) -c, d-\cos(x)\}$ which is positive $\implies$ ]$\cos(x)-\varepsilon,\cos(x)+\varepsilon[\subseteq]a,b[$.
Using the fact that $\cos(x)$ is 1-Lipschits, Let $r=\varepsilon$. Then $\forall y\in $ $]x-r, x+r[$ $\iff$ $|x-y|\lt r $ $\implies$ $|\cos(x) - \cos(y)|\lt r=\varepsilon$ $\iff$ $\cos(y) \in ]\cos(x)-\varepsilon, \cos(x)+\varepsilon[$ $\implies $ $\cos(]x-r, x+r[)\subseteq ]\cos(x)-\varepsilon,\cos(x)+\varepsilon[\subseteq ]a,b[$ $\iff$ $]x-r, x+r[\subseteq cos^{-1}(]\cos(x)-\varepsilon,\cos(x)+\varepsilon[)\subseteq \cos^{-1}(]a,b[)$.
Conclusion: $\forall y \in f^{-1}(]a,b[) , \exists r>0 : ]x-r, x+r[\subseteq cos^{-1}(]a,b[)$ $\implies$ $\cos^{-1}(]a,b[) \in \mathcal{T_\mathbb{R}}$ $\iff$ $\cos(x)$ is continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$